# Hostname Variable in shell script (NOT FQDN)

Tags: linux, bash, f5

I'm looking for a way to bind the hostname of my device to a variable in a shell script. However, I do not want to use the FQDN which is output from $HOSTNAME. Is there another simple method I can use to do this other name performing string manipulation on $HOSTNAME output?

Thanks

Comment: `HOST=${HOSTNAME%%.*}`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks dude

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVER="'hostname'"
echo "$SERVER"
HOST=${HOSTNAME%%.*}
echo "$HOST"
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to actually break each command out onto it's own line so it's clear they are separate commands, not one long string.